# How do I modify an outline in Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

I can't for the life of me work out how to modify an outline in Office 2010.

I have this outline and the different levels have specific formatting, indenting, etc.

I created it ages ago and know how to do it, but in Office 2010 I can't find where you edit the styles for the outline. I searched high and low and searched around, no luck.

Comment: You may also look at [How to add custom styles to navigation pane](http://superuser.com/questions/810243/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

On the Home tab, it shows all the outline levels. Right-click the desired level and select Modify.

In the bottom left of that dialog is a Format button.

Answer (score 0):

Is it Home/Paragraph/List/New MultiLevel List or New List style?